# Npm package.json inheritance

Tags: maven, npm, package

Is there a mechanism in npm like parent pom in Maven.
The goal is to have a common base configuration for scripts, dependencies, devDependencies.
Not based on templates like yeoman or so, but based on a parent version. So that, any project that changes his parent version gets the changes in this parent automatically.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Currently there is no built-in npm mechanism to achieve this, and there's not likely to be one in the future.

See the discussion [here](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/8112) and this [comment](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/8112#issuecomment-192489694) particularly.

Answer (score 14):

We built https://github.com/Cosium/dry-dry.
Its only purpose is to add package.json inheritance capability.
It delegates all commands to npm.

Update: This repository has been archived by the owner on Sep 9, 2022

Comment: Dude this is amazing! Just what we were starting to feel we should do, but you did it and did it well! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Yarn has this feature ([workspaces](https://yarnpkg.com/features/workspaces)), I recommend using yarn for this.

Comment: This won't help with extending the packages, workspaces solves a different problem - working on multiple packages within the same monorepo

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to consider is to have a package A that you publish (e.g. in a private registry) that "bundles" versions of various packages you wish to use. List them as `peerDependencies` in package A. Then, require A as a dependency in your project. Any consumer of package A would simply update package A to pull in new versions of those "bundled" dependencies. Two complications with this approach to consider:

1. How specific should those `peerDependencies` be? If you use loose specificity then each consumer of A could have different versions. This is useful if you want to allow consumers to upgrade as they see fit, or perhaps negotiate specific versions if needed.
2. Being able to do autocomplete on A's dependencies, e.g. in VSCode, requires additional effort, see https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39911#issuecomment-1179167693. By default, only direct dependencies in the project consuming A will autocomplete; dependencies of A would not autocomplete.