# Inherit or share package.json dependencies

Tags: npm, yarnpkg, package.json, package-managers

We got couple of different projects that are using main dependencies like React and TypeScript packages. Each of those projects(maintained by different dev team) is using diferent version of React and TypeScript - question here:

Is there any clever way to share/inherit/force to use specific version of main dependencies across all those projects? i.e.:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Npm package.json inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42441543/npm-package-json-inheritance)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is definitely possible. Simplest way is to create an npm module with the required common dependencies in a package.json file and publish this into your repo. Then in the projects, require that published npm module as a dependency. The projects can than further require other dependencies and override any from the parent if needed.