# How can I share engines from root package.json in a Lerna repo to all repo package.json config files?

Tags: node.js, json, npm, package.json

I have a Lerna monorepo, and in the root of the repo I set the version of Node that I need:

```json
"engines": {
  "node": ">=12.16.1"
},
```

In each individual repo in my `packages` and `tasks` directories, I'm copypasta'ing this information. I'd like to have a single place to set this and pick it up in all the subordinate `package.json` files. Is there any easy way to do so?

Comment: npm doesn't provide a built-in feature to support [package.json inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42441543/npm-package-json-inheritance/42448980#42448980), nor does lerna provide such a mechanism according to [issue #2820](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/issues/2820).