# Is there a method to separate dependencies object from package.json file of an angular project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm, package.json

**Here is the scenario**
I have multiple angular applications which belong to the same project. When I needed to upgrade an `npm package,` I need to change all the package.json files in each application. I tried mono repo, but it does not apply to my project because `npm scripts` are not the same as all apps.

So I want to separate the node dependencies from applications and keep npm scripts of the `package.json` files.

Is there a way to separate only the dependencies object from the package.json file? OR any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood well this could not be done with npm but seems like it can be achieved with yarn workspaces:

- https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/workspaces/

Guide for installing yarn:

- https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install/

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately npm do not support package.json inheritance. See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42441543/npm-package-json-inheritance).

On the other side why don't you customize your npm scripts? create alias for every npm command.
e.g.

```
"test-app1": "ng test app1",
"test-app2": "ng test app2 --code-coverage --no-watch --no-progress --browsers ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox",
```